# What's the recommended 'design pattern' for exposing data via class variables?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I've seen quite a few modules allow people to access data using:

```
print blah.name
```

As opposed to:

```
print blah.get_name()
```

Given the name is a a static variable, it seems like a better choice to use the variable method rather than calling a function.

I'm wondering what the best 'design' is for implementing this myself. For example, given a `Person` object, how should I expose the `name` and `age` ?

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, id):

        self.name = self.get_name(id)
        self.age  = self.get_age(id)

    def get_name(self, id=None):

        if not id:
            return self.name
        else:
            # sql query to get the name
```

This would allow me to:

```
x = Person
print x.name
```

Is there a recommended alternative?

Comment: "Given the name is a a static variable"  "class variables".  Both are completely wrong.   Your examples are all simply instance variables.  Neither class variable, nor static variable.  Please fix the question and the title to replace "static variable" and "class variable" with "instance variable".

Answer (score 5):

Python [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) are designed to resolve this issue.

Properties allow the phases `blah.name`, `blah.name = x`, and `del blah.name` to automatically invoke getter, setter, and deleter methods, if such methods have been defined.

Comment: @greg It is the standard, well-defined, and well-implemented way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, but I think you're overthinking it.  Unless you need to do something special in the getter or setter, the attributes don't need to be declared.  You just start using them when you need them, like this:

```
class Person:
    pass

x = Person
x.name = "test"
print x.name
```

If you do need to do something special in the getter or setter, like a SQL query, try this:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._name = None
        self._name_changed = False

    @property
    def name(self):
        if not self._name:
             self._name = 'select sql query'
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value
        self._name_changed = True

    def save(self):
        if self._name_changed:
            print 'update sql query set name=' + self._name
        self._name_changed = False

x = Person()
x.name = 'test'
print x.name
x.save()
```

Comment: I was thinking in terms of having a Person.save() function. If they were to edit the name/age and call save(), the database would be updated to reflect the changes. Using `property`, it seems I can define which variables will be saved when they change them

Answer (score 1):

Given your example you might want to take a look at [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and its ORM. It does a lot of that work for you. It already maps columns as object attributes.

Comment: I do use sqlalchemy to map my attributes to columns. I like to create wrapper objects, though. I'd create the ORM class to create the mappings and then a new class that has get_name(), set_age() etc.

Comment: @greg why? What do you achieve by that?